Run a command only during a defined time in shell script
I am trying to capture some details in a log file and would want that these details about my virtual machine should be captured only between 23:00 until 01:00. i am going to run this using nohup in the background like - nohup script.sh & and The script should only start running at 23:00 until 01:00. I have tried the below but it doesnt seem to do what i excepted:-
#!/bin/bash     
prodStartTime="230000"
prodEndTime="010000"
logfile=/tmp/processrunning.txt
touch $logfile

while true
do
currentTime=`date +"%H%M%S"`
if [[ $currentTime -ge $prodStartTime && $currentTime -le $prodEndTime ]];
  then
  ps aux | sort -nrk 3,3 | head -n 5 > $logfile
else
  :
fi
sleep 30
done


Can't you set up a cron job instead?

This sounds like a job for systemd-timer or cron.

Use cron or at (see man at) for starting the script. See timeout (man timeout) for ensuring that the script terminates 2 hours later.

@oguzismail we do not have and cant have any scheduler running at that machine.

What else can you tell us about that machine? Like, which operating system does it run? Do you have GNU date on it?

think about what that conditional is testing for .... how can $currentTime be both greater than '230000' and less than '010000'?

What OS is this? systemd-timer is built into systemd, so you already have it on basically all modern Linux systems that aren't dedicated-purpose embedded systems (which are also unlikely to have bash and may require implementing POSIX-compliant shell scripts).

Use timestamps and sleep as much as possible, especially before start
#!/usr/bin/env bash

prodStartTs=$(date -d 'today 23:00:00' +%s) # "230000"
prodEndTs=$(date -d 'tomorrow 01:00:00' +%s) # "010000"
logFile="/tmp/processrunning-$(date +%Y%m%d).txt"

if [[ -f "$logFile" ]] # todays logfile already exist
then # this is an error
  printf 'Log file %s already exist!' "$logFile" >&2
  exit 1
fi
touch "$logFile"

secBeforeStart=$((prodStartTs - EPOCHSECONDS))
if [[ $secBeforeStart -gt 0 ]] # it is not time to start
then sleep "$secBeforeStart" # all the remaining seconds before start
fi

while [[ $EPOCHSECONDS -le $prodEndTs ]] # it is not time to stop
do # all this
  ps aux | sort -nrk 3,3 | head -n 5 
  sleep 30 # every 30 seconds
done > "$logFile" # all logged to logFile

bash "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" # Rerun self


Use timestamps:
$ date +%s -d23:00
1712606400

$ date +%s -d01:00
1712527200

$ date -d@1712527200
Mon Apr  8 01:00:00 MSK 2024

$ date -d@1712606400
Mon Apr  8 23:00:00 MSK 2024

In your case:
prodStartTime=$(date +%s -d23:00)
prodEndTime=$(date +%s -d01:00)
currentTime=$(date +%s)


Use crontab to define when your script should run

   The time and date fields are:

          field          allowed values
          -----          --------------
          minute         0-59
          hour           0-23
          day of month   1-31
          month          1-12 (or names, see below)
          day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sunday, or use names)


* 23,0,1 * * * /path/to/your/script

this would run every minute, so if you want to run every 30 secs you may need to invoke your command twice
cmd() {
  ps aux | sort -nrk 3,3 | head -n 5 > /tmp/processrunning.txt
}

cmd
sleep 30
cmd



[[ $currentTime -ge $prodStartTime && $currentTime -le $prodEndTime ]];


Substituting -ge for >= and -le for <= and expanding the variables, results in:
$currentTime >= 230000 && $currentTime <= 010000

How can a number be greater than 230000 and lower than 10000 at the same time?
Additionally, numbers with leading 0 are octal numbers. 010000 is equal 4096.
You want logical or between expression. I.e. the time has to be lower than 10000 or greater than 230000. $currentTime >= 230000 || $currentTime <= 10000.
Btw, it would be much simpler to just compare hours anyway.
Additionally, check your script with shellcheck.

I did not understand how Or can be used? I have a limitation in this machine that any scheduler cannot be used in it. Can you elaborate on the OR part and how to run it like run when time is between 11 to 1 do this and other time do nothing and then the if part should again start after 5 mins.

I do not understand. Instead of logical && between relations, I suggested to use logical ||. A logical or and logical and is a logical connective between true or false values. I have a limitation in this machine that any scheduler Such requirement is very vague at best. You are in the process of writing a scheduler. You program is a scheduler.|
